# Error when nothing passed into PHP Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have code which basically add Id Numbers to an array and then on another page it uses these Id Numbers to retrieve the relevant row information. The Id number are added to the array by checking a check box next to the items. When none of items are checked and the form is submitted obviously nothing is added to the array and outputs the error:

> Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...ELECT this1, this2, this3 FROM table1 WHERE Ref IN () ^ in ***_*__*_*__*_*__** on line 49
>
> Warning: pg_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** on line 57

My code to get the checked values and using the array is:

```
session_start();
$games = $_POST['games'];
$list = implode(',', $games);
```

---

This is now my code, but still cant get SESSION to work?

```
$_SESSION["gamelist"] = $games; 
$games = $_POST['games']; 
if (!empty($games)){ 
$games = $_POST['games']; 
$list = implode(',', $games);
}else { 
header('Location:./home.php'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the array is empty before using it.

```
$games = $_POST['games'];

if (!empty($games)){
    $games = $_POST['games'];
    $list = implode(',', $games);

}else {
    // things to do when the array is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ibu answered the first part, the second part about creating the session is pretty simple, once you know your array isn't empty:

```
$_SESSION["pick-a-name"] = $games;
```

More details on the $_SESSION functionality can be found here: https://www.php.net/session_start

**Update (11/21/2013):**

```
session_start();
//$games = $_POST['games']; 
$games = array(1=>"element1",
          2=>"element2",
          3=>"element3");

if (!empty($games)){ 
     $_SESSION["gamelist"] = $games; 
     $list = implode(',', $games);
}else {
    header('Location:./home.php'); 
}

echo $list."<br />";
print_r($_SESSION["gamelist"]);
```

This block of code works perfectly for me. I tested with $games being set and without and both conditions were met properly. What error are you still getting?

Comment: Still can't get session to work for some reason, I have edited code above, if you can see thanks :)